# to foreign server, aspx dynamically sending browser java script via <script src=

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, document.write, response.write

Thank to you all in advance for helping.
Here's something I have that is working up to a certain point.

From an html page on a foreign server (not mine) I have this HTML line

```
<script src="http://myserver.xyz/loadthis.aspx?BA_TYPE=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

"loadthis.aspx" page load event on my server contains this (I made it as simple as I can for this question, a lot more is happening in there but this is the subject of the question)

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Write("document.write('<a href= etc...")
Response.End()
Response.Close()
```

This works perfectly, dynamically loading the html

But I also need sometime to dynamically send a script like this one below instead.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-8271739469826977"
         data-ad-slot="3666463954"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
```

I've tried things like this:
where Str_BACODE as string containing the above code

```
Response.Write("document.write('" + StrBA_CODE + "')")
```

- This does nothing.  Do I need to use another javascript method
  replacing document.write?
- Do I first need to modify the script I'm sending? Modifying what/how?

How could this be resolved?

Remember my routine(aspx) is used from other sites, not my server.

Hope I made this clear enough?
Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Use next:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("MyTool", "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");
Response.Write(@"<ins class='adsbygoogle'
                 style='display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px'
                 data-ad-client='ca-pub-8271739469826977'
                 data-ad-slot='3666463954'></ins>
                 <script>
                     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                 </script>");
```

Comment: thanks!  did you try it?  those two lines are executed but nothing is displayed on the browser.  Here's the coded used (posted as an answer to my question, did not fit here)  Let me know.

Comment: Anyone tried his solution? does not work here... I posted the vb aspx code I converted @khazratbek created

Comment: @Mephisto999, I tried this solution, and it was showing some google ads. That's why I posted it here

Comment: see bottom I've added all code in a small test file.  Thank you for your help! appreciated!